# Possible sybase sql query

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm trying to get back into sql after many years away. I'm new to Sybase as well. Can you please suggest a possible query for the following problem?

There is a table called vegetables as follows.

```
| product | price | date     |
| beans   | 1.78  | 20040903 |
| beans   | 1.79  | 20040902 |
| potato  | 1.78  | 20040902 |
```

I need to get the latest available prices for each vegetable. The intended database is sybase.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the `max(date)` for each `product` and then join back to your table:

```
select v1.product, 
  v1.price,
  v1.date
from vegetables v1
inner join
(
  select product, max(date) MaxDate
  from vegetables
  group by product
) v2
  on v1.product = v2.product
  and v1.date = v2.maxdate;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41951/1) (Demo is SQL Server but the syntax should be valid).

If your version of Sybase supports windowing functions, then you can use the following:

```
select product, price, date
from 
(
  select product, price, date,
    row_number() over(partition by product order by date desc) rn
  from vegetables
) v
where rn = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41951/2)

Comment: **`select product, max(date) MaxDate
  from vegetables
  group by product`** --Why can't we use this Query? **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41951/4)**

Comment: Because they want the `price` associated with the max date, if you add that you will have to group by it as well and the values are distinct.

Comment: @bluefeet Excellent answer. And great tip with sql fiddle (didn't know about that one). I was thinking conceptually about doing such operations but wasn't sure about the syntax. Now that I see it it makes sense. The 'row number over partition' syntax is new to me. Will have to look that up. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @junkie You are welcome, I don't think all versions of Sybase support the row_number so you will have to check with your version. :)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, standard SQL queries should work, for the most part, on Sybase databases. I'm no DB admin, but sometihng like this might work:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  vegetables v 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT 
      iv.id, 
      MAX(iv.date) AS date
    FROM 
      vegetables iv 
    GROUP BY 
      iv.id
  ) maxv ON maxv.date = v.date
```